# One-time running Python code when AWS EC2 instance start

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm

I have a two `EC2` instances named `"aws-example"` and `"aws-sandbox"`. At same time, they are docker machines. `"aws-example"` is a manager and `"aws-sandbox"` is a worker in a docker-swarm.

I wrote two Python script, when run the script in `"aws-example"`, it stopped to `"aws-sandbox"` instance and start it again.

When I run the script in `"aws-sandbox"`, worker has to left the swarm and join again.

I do by my hand all of this process. However, I have to automate that. How I do the one-time running Python script in `"aws-sandbox"` when the `"aws-sandbox"` instance started? I've had investigate to services AWS Lambda, CloudWatch etc. and I'm very confused. Are here any person who have clear pathway?

Comment: `@reboot /path/to/script.py` in cron should work. Check this https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/running-scripts-at-boot

Comment: Let me put it in answer, so that anyone else will know it.

Comment: Can use run control scripts I.e. /etc/rc.local (ref. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md) or /etc/rcN.d (ref.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4073/6jd67r96g/index.html)- Check out similar questions / answers like: https://askubuntu.com/a/9880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `@reboot /path/to/script.py` in cron, it should work.

For more info check [this](https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/running-scripts-at-boot) out.